# Cannot construct instance of `reactor.core.publisher.Mono` Spring Cloud OpenFeign and Spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, project-reactor

**Goal**: migration from Spring Boot 1.x (webMvc) to version 2 (webFlux) and Spring Cloud Edgware SR2 to FinchleyM8 (awaiting release version).

**Problem**: Feign -> OpenFeign. OpenFeign under the hood uses RxJava but WebFlux - Reactor3. At the current moment when I using Mono as returned type, I have got an error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class reactor.core.publisher.Mono]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `reactor.core.publisher.Mono` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

**Code example**:

```
@FeignClient(name = "thirdpartyresource", url = "${third.party.resource.url}")
public interface ThirdPartyResource {

    @PostMapping(value = "/validate", consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    Mono<ValidationResultDto> validate(MultiValueMap multiValueMap); // WORKS BAD
    // Single<ValidationResultDto> validate(MultiValueMap multiValueMap); WORKS WELL
}
```

**Question**: 
Do I need to create my own converter Single to Mono or it's some problems of spring-cloud-starter-openfeign and all should work OOTB?

Comment: It does not out of the box.

Comment: Since Spring provides Reactor 3 as default, would be more suitable when projects from the Springs family also use it. Thanks

Comment: Working on it https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/pull/11

Comment: **Thanks, guys!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use those methods to adapt:

For `Single<T> rxJavaSingle`

```
Mono.from(RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(rxJavaSingle))
```

For `Completable rxJavaCompletable`

```
Mono.from(RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(rxJavaCompletable))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `reactor.core.publisher.Mono` belongs to the `spring-boot-starter-webflux` jar.

Get the latest version of it from the [mvn repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux).

Then add it to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also do remove `spring-boot-starter-web` from your pom.xml, just in case if you have it.

```
<!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>-->
```

This fixed the issue!