# How to send a flux of integers from one microservice to another

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am new to Spring WebFlux and WebClient. I am working on a PoC where I have designed two microservices. I am trying to send a flux of integers using a post request from service A which I intend to consume in service B. I took help from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142662/is-it-possible-to-pass-flux-to-the-body-of-webclient-post) to develop the  the sender (A) and the receiver (B) code.

**Service A:**

```
 Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5);
 WebClient.create("http://localhost:9002/registry")
          .post()
          .uri("/packages")
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .body(integerFlux, Integer.class)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(Void.class)
          .block();
```

**Service B:**

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/packages", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createPackage(@RequestBody Flux<Integer> integerFlux) {
        this.registryService.createPackage(integerFlux);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

When I execute the post request from service A, I get the following error logs:

**Service A:**

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from POST http://localhost:9002/registry/packages
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:239) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 500 from POST http://localhost:9002/registry/packages [DefaultWebClient]
```

**Service B:**

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class reactor.core.publisher.Flux]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `reactor.core.publisher.Flux` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `reactor.core.publisher.Flux` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

I also tried changing the content-type to **application/nd-json**, but in that case I am getting a **415 Unsupported Media Type Error**. The fix in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299224/cannot-construct-instance-of-reactor-core-publisher-mono-spring-cloud-openfeig) did not help me either.

Can anyone help me understand where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer with good news.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue is the use of `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`. It should be `consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE}`. Similarly, on the client `.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` should be `.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)`

Here is a complete example (client & server) of passing a `Flux<Integer>` as body *and* receiving one as a response.

**Controller**

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/post", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE})
    Flux<Integer> create(@RequestBody Flux<Integer> integerStream) {
        integerStream.log().subscribe(i -> {
            System.out.println(i);
        });

        return Flux.just(5, 6, 7);
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class PostFlux {

    private static WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        Flux<Integer> result = webClient.post().uri("/post").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)
            .body(integerFlux, Integer.class).retrieve().bodyToFlux(Integer.class);
            
        List<Integer> list = result.collectList().block();
    
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version> <!--or 2.7.10 -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>monostuff</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>monostuff</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version><!--or 11 -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The server can also be tested with a curl as follows. Note how a Flux is posted using newlines between each value.

Windows: `curl http://localhost:8080/post -H "Content-type: application/x-ndjson" --data "1\n2\n3\n4\n"`

Unix: curl `'http://localhost:8080/post' --header 'Content-type: application/x-ndjson' --data '1\n2\n3\n4\n'`

The server can be tested with Postman by following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437217/how-to-send-elasticsearch-multi-search-request-in-postman).